# youtube buttons don't work in chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, youtube

I've been using Youtube through chromium on Raring for over a year now.  Suddenly, yesterday, some buttons on Youtube stopped working.

1. When viewing a particular video, the buttons for "show more", "add to", etc. do nothing.
2. Clicking my profile name/icon (upper-right corner) does nothing.
3. When I search in youtube, only the first 5 or 6 results show a thumbnail.  The rest have a blank white box.  Similarly, if I just go to youtube.com, none of the video thumbnails load.

Attempted solutions:

1. If I use Firefox, everything works fine
2. I cleared the cache for Chromium.  Nothing changed.
3. checked for chromium updates.  Is already up-to-date.
4. `aptitude reinstall ...` .  Nothing changed.
5. checked/installed/updated adobe flash player and pepper flash.  Nothing changed.
6. disabled all extensions except for youtube Adblock.  nothing changed.
7. Checked youtube from my work computer (Debian) with Chromium - works fine.

Comment: Raring has reached End-Of-Life. Please upgrade to Saucy or Trusty.

Comment: @saiarcot895  How likely is that to be the explanation for these issues?

Comment: Of that I'm not sure. But I do know that if you stay on Raring, you won't get any updates for anything (including Chromium), and that you will be running Chromium 31 (the current version is Chromium 34).